# how to properly implement AMP form POST submit?

Tags: php, amp-html

I ran across this [post](https://searchwilderness.com/amp-forms/) on how to implement AMP form POST. I followed the example:

```
<form novalidate="" accept-charset="UTF-8" action-xhr="process.php" target="_top"...>...</form
```

But I'm still getting this error:

```
action-xhr must start with "https://" or "//" or be relative and served from either https or from localhost. Invalid value
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hope this help you : https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/#form-submission-with-page-reload

Comment: your action-xhr should be started with "https://" or "//" , example "//yourdomain.tld/process.php"  or  "https://yourwebsite.tld/process.php"